# get rotation of the screen from a class that extends View

Tags: android

I've got a class

```
class myView extends SurfaceView
```

How can i get the rotation of the screen from there?

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate an OrientationEventListener. Just make sure to disable it when you are not using it because the SensorManager will drain the battery.

```
public class OELActivity extends Activity{

  OrientationEventListener mOrientationEventListener;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mOrientationEventListener = (new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {
      @Override
      public void onOrientationChanged(int aangle) {
          //Do your thing here. angle is in degrees
      }});
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {

    if (myOrientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation()){
      myOrientationEventListener.enable();
    } else {
      //handle the fact that you can't detect the orientation
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mOrientationEventListener.disable();
  }
}
```